# A result of generalised pigeonhole principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I understand the proof of generalised pigeonhole principle but there is a result which follows from it is not making sense to me.

The text is taken from Discrete Mathematics by Kenneth Rosen :

> A common type of problem asks for the minimum number of objects such
>   that at least $r$ of these objects must be in one of $k$ boxes when these
>   objects are distributed among the boxes. When we have $N$ objects, the
>   generalized pigeonhole principle tells us there must be at least $r$
>   objects in one of the boxes as long as  $\lceil N/k \rceil \geq r$.  The
>   smallest integer $N$ with $N/k > r − 1$, namely, $N = k(r − 1) +
> > 1$, is the smallest integer satisfying the inequality $\lceil N/k \rceil \geq r$. Could a smaller value of $N$ suffice? The answer is no, because if
>   we had $k(r − 1)$ objects, we could put $r − 1$ of them in each of the $k$ boxes and no box would have at least $r$ objects.
>
> When thinking about problems of this type, it is useful to consider
>   how you can avoid having at least $r$ objects in one of the boxes as you
>   add successive objects. To avoid adding a $r$th object to any box, you
>   eventually end up with r − 1 objects in each box. There is no way to
>   add the next object without putting an $r$th object in that box.

I don't understand what is the purpose of $N/k > r − 1$ and how it is being used in $N = k(r − 1) +1$.

I get the idea (if I am right) that they are trying to prove what is the minimum number objects in a set of boxes if there is at least one box contains more than one object.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generalised pidgeonhole principle answers the question of how many objects are required to make sure that the **fullest** box always contains at least $r$ objects.

If $N/k = r-1$, then $N = k(r-1)$ and all of the boxes can be filled with $r-1$ objects and hence $N$ is not large enough. That is why $N/k > r-1$, and thus $N > k(r-1)$. The smallest integer $N$ satisfying $N > k(r-1)$ is $k(r-1) + 1$.